# How can I fix the fatal error C1060 that occurs when using Nuitka to compile .py to .exe?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, nuitka

At the end of compiling the .py file in .exe error C1060 occurs, how to solve this problem?

Nuitka command:

```
nuitka --onefile --jobs=4 --disable-ccache --plugin-enable=pyqt5 --windows-icon-from-ico=youtube-downloader-icon.ico downloader.py
```

Full terminal output:

```
E:\code\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\YOUTUBE_DOWNLOADER_2>nuitka --onefile --jobs=4 --disable-ccache --plugin-enable=pyqt5 --windows-icon-from-ico=youtube-downloader-icon.ico downloader.py
Nuitka-Options:INFO: Used command line options: --onefile --jobs=4 --disable-ccache --plugin-enable=pyqt5 --windows-icon-from-ico=youtube-downloader-icon.ico downloader.py
Nuitka:WARNING: The Python version '3.11' is only experimentally supported by Nuitka '1.5.4', but an upcoming release
Nuitka:WARNING: will change that. In the mean time use Python version '3.10' instead or newer Nuitka.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: pyqt5: For the obsolete PyQt5 the Nuitka support is incomplete. Threading, callbacks to compiled
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: functions, etc. may not be working.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/pyqt5.html
Nuitka:INFO: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '1.5.4' on Python '3.11' commercial grade 'not installed'.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pyqt5: Injecting pre-module load code for module 'PyQt5':
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pyqt5:     Adding binary folder to runtime 'PATH' environment variable for proper Qt loading.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pyqt5: Injecting post-module load code for module 'PyQt5.QtCore':
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pyqt5:     Setting Qt library path to distribution folder. We need to avoid loading target
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pyqt5:     system Qt plugins, which may be from another Qt version.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: multiprocessing: Injecting pre-module load code for module 'multiprocessing':
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: multiprocessing:     Monkey patching "multiprocessing" load environment.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: multiprocessing: Injecting post-module load code for module 'multiprocessing':
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: multiprocessing:     Monkey patching "multiprocessing" for compiled methods.
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pkg-resources: Injecting post-module load code for module 'pkg_resources':
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: pkg-resources:     Registering Nuitka loader with "pkg_resources".
Nuitka-Plugins:INFO: options-nanny: Note, when using 'PyQt5', consider using '--disable-console' option. Otherwise a terminal window will open. However for debugging, terminal output is the easiest way to see informative traceback information.
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl 14.3).
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Slow C compilation detected, used 60s so far, scalability problem.
Unexpected output from this command:
Unexpected output from this command:
cl /Fomodule.yt_dlp.extractor.youtube.obj /c "module.yt_dlp.extractor.youtube.cpp" /TP /nologo /Ox /GF /Gy /EHsc /J /Gd /bigobj /MT /D__NUITKA_NO_ASSERT__ /D_NUITKA_STANDALONE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_MODE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_TEMP_BOOL /D_NUITKA_CONSTANTS_FROM_RESOURCE /D_NUITKA_FROZEN=155 /D_NUITKA_EXE /D_NUITKA_PLUGIN_MULTIPROCESSING_ENABLED=1 /IE:\code\Python\include /I. /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\include /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\static_src
cl /Fomodule.yt_dlp.extractor.zattoo.obj /c "module.yt_dlp.extractor.zattoo.cpp" /TP /nologo /Ox /GF /Gy /EHsc /J /Gd /bigobj /MT /D__NUITKA_NO_ASSERT__ /D_NUITKA_STANDALONE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_MODE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_TEMP_BOOL /D_NUITKA_CONSTANTS_FROM_RESOURCE /D_NUITKA_FROZEN=155 /D_NUITKA_EXE /D_NUITKA_PLUGIN_MULTIPROCESSING_ENABLED=1 /IE:\code\Python\include /I. /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\include /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\static_src
module.yt_dlp.extractor.youtube.cpp(127845): fatal error C1060: Є®¬ЇЁ«пв®аг ­Ґ еў в Ґв а §¬Ґа  ЄгзЁ
scons: *** [module.yt_dlp.extractor.youtube.obj] Error 2
module.yt_dlp.extractor.zattoo.cpp(46870): fatal error C1060: Є®¬ЇЁ«пв®аг ­Ґ еў в Ґв а §¬Ґа  ЄгзЁ
Backend C: 97.6%|████████████████████████▍| 1197/1227scons: *** [module.yt_dlp.extractor.zattoo.obj] Error 2
Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Running 'cl /Fomodule.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.obj /c "module.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.cpp" /TP /nologo /Ox /GF /Gy /EHsc /J /Gd /bigobj /MT /D__NUITKA_NO_ASSERT__ /D_NUITKA_STANDALONE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_MODE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_TEMP_BOOL /D_NUITKA_CONSTANTS_FROM_RESOURCE /D_NUITKA_FROZEN=155 /D_NUITKA_EXE /D_NUITKA_PLUGIN_MULTIPROCESSING_ENABLED=1 /IE:\\code\\Python\\include /I. /IE:\\code\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\nuitka\\build\\include /IE:\\code\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\nuitka\\build\\static_src' took 262.56 seconds
Unexpected output from this command:
cl /Fomodule.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.obj /c "module.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.cpp" /TP /nologo /Ox /GF /Gy /EHsc /J /Gd /bigobj /MT /D__NUITKA_NO_ASSERT__ /D_NUITKA_STANDALONE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_MODE /D_NUITKA_ONEFILE_TEMP_BOOL /D_NUITKA_CONSTANTS_FROM_RESOURCE /D_NUITKA_FROZEN=155 /D_NUITKA_EXE /D_NUITKA_PLUGIN_MULTIPROCESSING_ENABLED=1 /IE:\code\Python\include /I. /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\include /IE:\code\Python\Lib\site-packages\nuitka\build\static_src
module.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.cpp(469234): fatal error C1060: Є®¬ЇЁ«пв®аг ­Ґ еў в Ґв а §¬Ґа  ЄгзЁ
Backend C: 97.7%|████████████████████████▍| 1199/1227scons: *** [module.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.obj] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i think this will help
try python 3.10.1
and reinstall nuitka
and try this commend :

```
python -m nuitka --onefile --include-package=PyQt5 --include-package-data=PyQt5 --follow-imports --enable-plugin=pyqt5 --include-qt-plugins=all main.py
```

Comment: Nuitka:INFO: Keeping dist folder 'downloader.dist' for inspection, no need to use it.
Nuitka:INFO: Keeping build directory 'downloader.build'.
Nuitka:INFO: Successfully created 'downloader.exe'.

Thank you bro, you helped a lot, I suspect that the error was in the old version of nuitka in which python 3.11 was supported experimentally, after I updated the compiler, the python 3.11 warning disappeared and the compilation worked